# Does ordering a column before partitioning make a difference

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, partitioning

I'm wondering if ordering a dataframe before partitioning will make a difference in computation speed/resource consumption. To be specific, I have parquet files saved in Databricks and I want to filter on two columns, but the other one is too granular to only partition on it. If first ordering the dataset, I see the second column is ordered in the partition, but does it actually make any sense for Databricks? Will Databricks recognize that the records are sorted on the second column and speed up the read?

I want to look for movies based on their year, but sometimes also based on their name. But, movies name is too cardinal for it to be a partition itself, so I didn't include it in the partitionBy.

```
df.orderBy("year","movie_name").write.partitionBy("year").csv("dbfs:/FileStore/movies")
```

Is the above query any better than this one?

```
df.write.partitionBy("year").csv("dbfs:/FileStore/movies")
```

Or what's the best method for partitioning in such very cases? Year and Name will for sure be the two most used columns in the dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't gain anything by ordering before writing parquet file, because the information about the ordering is not persisted in the file itself.

You can verify this by using the `explain()` method of a dataframe. Let's do it ourselves:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("niceMovie2", 2020),
        ("niceMovie1", 2020),
        ("niceMovie3", 2021)
    ],
    ["Title", "Year"]
)

>>> df.show()
+----------+----+
|     Title|Year|
+----------+----+
|niceMovie2|2020|
|niceMovie1|2020|
|niceMovie3|2021|
+----------+----+
```

Let's write the dataframe to a parquet file without ordering and then reread it, filtering out a movie by `Year` and `Title`:

```py
df.write.partitionBy("Year").parquet("movies.parquet")
df2 = spark \
    .read \
    .parquet("movies.parquet") \
    .filter(col("Year") == 2020) \
    .filter(col("Title") == "niceMovie2")

>>> df2.explain()
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Filter (isnotnull(Title#4) AND (Title#4 = niceMovie2))
+- *(1) ColumnarToRow
   +- FileScan parquet [Title#4,Year#5] Batched: true, DataFilters: [isnotnull(Title#4), (Title#4 = niceMovie2)], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file:/somewhere/movies.parquet], PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(Year#5), (Year#5 = 2020)], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(Title), EqualTo(Title,niceMovie2)], ReadSchema: struct<Title:string>
```

As you can see in the physical plan, the file will be read and the partitioning will be used to efficiently remove unused years (see the `PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(Year #13), (Year#13 = 2020)]` bit).

Now let's do the same, but order the dataframe by `Title` before reading it:

```py
df.orderBy("Title").write.partitionBy("Year").parquet("moviesOrdered.parquet")
df3 = spark \
    .read \
    .parquet("movies.parquet") \
    .filter(col("Year") == 2020) \
    .filter(col("Title") == "niceMovie2")

>>> df3.explain()                                                               
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Filter (isnotnull(Title#0) AND (Title#0 = niceMovie2))
+- *(1) ColumnarToRow
   +- FileScan parquet [Title#0,Year#1] Batched: true, DataFilters: [isnotnull(Title#0), (Title#0 = niceMovie2)], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file:/home/somewhere/moviesOrdered.parquet], PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(Year#1), (Year#1 = 2020)], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(Title), EqualTo(Title,niceMovie2)], ReadSchema: struct<Title:string>
```

You see that in this case, the physical plan is exactly the same. So there is no difference in performance.

Comment: Hello Koedlt, thank you! Do you have any tip how to partition the column with high cardinality (movie name) since the ordering doesn't help, or know any resources where to read about it?

Comment: Hmmm there are many variables here: How large is your data, and how large is your cluster? Also, how long are your spark jobs taking? And are you mostly interested in simply extracting 1 record from the parquet file?

Comment: i don't have any specific information right now about that, but i'm expecting a huge table (billions of record), and the cluster sized accordingly. In most scenarious, i will want to extract multiple movies based on their name and year (movies and year is an example, we can also think a transaction date and a bank account number where it's more like reality)

Comment: Hmm I wouldn't worry too much about this then. If your cluster is properly sized w.r.t. your data you're not doing any crazy things here. Your partitioning by year (depending on the cardinality of your years) will already give you a great performance boost. What you could also look at is how many part-files will get created within each year partition. Try to get each part-file to be around 100MB, that's a good first approach. You can have control over this by doing something like `df.repartition(NR_OF_PARTITIONS, someOtherCol).write.partitionBy("Year").parquet(filename)`